# Unable to write to STDIN of C application using pipes created in PHP

Tags: php, html, c, linux, web

This is a server client web socket program, when client send "exe" command the server executes a C application.
The output of the c application is read from STDOUT by server and displayed on the client browser.
Now there is a C application that requires a user input(scanf), we saved the input in a txt file. We read the input 
and write it to the stdin of the c program. The problem is that it seems that the C program is not accepting the input
that we are writting on the stdin. When i tried this code without any stream select it was working and displaying the sum of two numbers read from input file, but when i place it in stream select command its creating problem. My complete server code is  at the end.

**a part of server code that is creating  child process on a client request**

```
if(strcmp($user_message, "exe") == 0 ) {
     echo "Executing a process\n";
     $cwd = '/var/www/html/test/websockets' ;

     $process = proc_open($exe_command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);//creating child process
     sleep(1);

     if (is_resource($process))
     {
         echo "Process Created";

         $read_socks[] = $pipes[1];//add a descriptor 
         $stdout = array($pipes[1]);//save stdout in a variable defined above
         $stdin  = array($pipes[0]);

         print_r ($stdout); 
         print_r ($stdin);
      } 
     }
     else
     {
       echo "Passing value to the C program".$user_message;

       //Read input.txt by line and store it in an array
       $input = array(); 
       $input = file('/var/www/html/test/websockets/input.txt');

     echo "INPUT";
     print_r($input);
     echo "\n";

     //Feed the input (hardcoded)
     $bytes = fwrite($stdin[0], "$input[0] $input[1]");
     echo "Bytes written:".$bytes;
                 sleep(1);

             }
     }      
}
```

**add.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
      int first, second;

      printf("Enter two integers > \n");
      scanf("%d", &first);
      scanf("%d", &second);
      printf("The two numbers are: %d  %d\n", first, second);
      printf("Output: %d\n", first+second);
}
```

**input.txt**

```
2
4
```

**output**

```
Passing value to the C program3Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #11
)

INPUTArray
(
    [0] => 2

    [1] => 4

)

Bytes written:5
```

**By doing ps I get**

```
root      1173  1164  0 12:08 pts/6    00:00:00 tclsh /usr/bin/unbuffer /var/www/html/test/websockets/./add
root      1174  1173  0 12:08 pts/8    00:00:00 /var/www/html/test/websockets/./add
```

After bytes written the server is hanging there is no response from the C application i.e the addition result of 4+2.
Why there are two process of add i started 1 with proc open.

**complete server code**

```
     <?php
    execute_prog('unbuffer /var/www/html/test/websockets/./add');//unbuffer stdout
function execute_prog($exe)
{
        echo "[+execute_prog]";

        $host = 'localhost'; //host
        $port = '9000'; //port
        $null = NULL; //null var
            $read_socks;
            $new_client;


        $server = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:9000", $errno, $errorMessage);

        if ($server === false)
        {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
        }

        set_time_limit(1800);

        $exe_command = escapeshellcmd($exe);

        $descriptorspec = array(

                0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin -> for execution

                1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout -> for execution

                2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr 

            );

    //   $process = proc_open($exe_command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);//creating child process

//       if (is_resource($process))
          {
              $client_socks = array();
                      $read_socks = array($server);
                      $changed = array();
                      $stdout = NULL; 
                      $stdin = NULL; 

            while(1)
            {
                //prepare readable sockets
                $write  = NULL; 
                $err    = NULL;
                $except = NULL;
                            $changed = $read_socks;//by refrence
/*
                            echo "stdout:";
                            print_r ($stdout);
                echo "\n";

                echo "changed:";
                print_r ($changed);
                echo "\n";

                echo "read sock:";
                print_r ($read_socks);
                echo "\n";
*/
                if (false === ($num_changed_streams = stream_select($changed, $write, $except, 0)))
                {
                    /* Error handling */
                                echo "Errors\n";
                } 
                else if ($num_changed_streams > 0)
                {
                     /* At least on one of the streams something interesting happened */
                         echo "Data on ".$num_changed_streams." descriptor\n";

                                 if(in_array($stdout[0], $changed))
                     {
                         echo "Data on child process STDOUT\n";

                             $s = fgets($stdout[0]);

                         if( $s === false )
                                             {
                             // Hello program has finished.
                             echo 'Finished', PHP_EOL;

                             $s = NULL;
                             //ob_flush();
                             flush();

                             // Close all descriptors and return...
                                                    // break;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             echo $s."</br>";

                             //prepare data to be sent to client
                             $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$s, 'color'=>$user_color)));
                                                 foreach ($read_socks as $sock)
                                                     {  
                                                       if(($sock != $server) && ($sock != $stdout))
                                               fwrite($sock, $response_text, strlen($response_text));
                                                     }

                             $s = NULL;
                             //ob_flush();
                             flush();
                         }

                     }
                                     else if(in_array($server, $changed))
                     {
                       //new client
                                       echo "New Connection\n";

                       $new_client = stream_socket_accept($server);

                       if ($new_client)
                       {
                          //print remote client information, ip and port number
                          echo 'Connection accepted from ' . stream_socket_get_name($new_client, true) . "n";
                              $read_socks[] = $new_client;
                          echo "Now there are total ". count($read_socks) . " clients.n";
                       }

                                       $header = fread($new_client, 1024);//read data sent by the socket
                       perform_handshaking($header, $new_client, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

                       $ip = stream_socket_get_name($new_client, true);
                       $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
                                   fwrite($new_client,$response,strlen($response));

                       //delete the server socket from the read sockets
                       unset($changed[ array_search($server, $changed) ]);

                                     }
                     else if($write)
                     {
                         echo "Data on child process STDIN\n";

                     }
                     else if($err)
                     {
                         echo "Data on child process STDERR\n";

                     }
                                     else
                     {
                                             echo "Message from the client \n";
                         //message from existing client

                         foreach($changed as $sock)
                         {
                             $data = fread($sock, 128);
                                                     //echo "Data read:".$data." From sock:".$sock."\n"; 

                             if(!$data)
                             {
                                 unset($client_socks[ array_search($sock, $client_socks) ]);
                                 @fclose($sock);
                                 echo "A client disconnected. Now there are total ". count($client_socks) . " clients.n";
                                 continue;
                             }
                                                     else
                             {
                                 $received_text = unmask($data); //unmask data
                                 $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
                                 $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
                                 $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
                                 $user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color
                                                             //echo "name:".$user_name." user mesg:".$user_message."\n";

                                 //prepare data to be sent to client
                                 $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));

                                 fwrite($sock, $response_text, strlen($response_text));
//..................................................................................................................

                                                             if(strcmp($user_message, "exe") == 0 )
                                                             {
                                     echo "Executing a process\n";
                                     $cwd = '/var/www/html/test/websockets' ;

                                     $process = proc_open($exe_command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);//creating child process
                                     sleep(1);

                                     if (is_resource($process))
                                     {
                                         echo "Process Created";

                                         $read_socks[] = $pipes[1];//add a descriptor 
                                         $stdout = array($pipes[1]);//save stdout in a variable defined above
                                                                             $stdin  = array($pipes[0]);

                                         print_r ($stdout); 
                                                                             print_r ($stdin);
                                      } 
                                                             }
                                                             else
                                                             {
                                                                 echo "Passing value to the C program".$user_message;
                                                                 print_r ($stdin);
                                     echo "\n";
                                                                 //$input = array($user_message);
                                    // fwrite($stdin[0],"$input[0]");//,strlen($user_message));   

                                     //Read input.txt by line and store it in an array
                                                                 $input = array(); 
                                     $input = file('/var/www/html/test/websockets/input.txt');
                                                                 echo "INPUT";
                                                                 print_r($input);
                                                                 echo "\n";

                                     //Feed the input (hardcoded)
                                     $bytes = fwrite($stdin[0], "$input[0] $input[1]");// $input[1]");
                                     echo "Bytes written:".$bytes;

                                                             }
                                                     }      
                         } 
                                     }

                    $num_changed_streams = 0;
                }

            }

                    // close the listening socket
                    fclose($server);
            fclose($pipes[0]);
            fclose($pipes[1]);
            fclose($pipes[2]);
            echo "exitcode: ".proc_close($process)."\n";
        }   


    echo "[-execute_prog]";
//  return $ret;
}

 ?>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thank you!

**EDIT**

The following code writes to the stdin of a C application but when i tried to integrate in the above client server its not working.

```
 <?php
 //descriptors to be handled by parent
 $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("file", "/var/www/html/websockets/error.txt", "a")
    );

    // define current working directory where files would be stored
    $cwd = '/var/www/html' ;

    $child_proc = escapeshellcmd("unbuffer /var/www/html/test/websockets/./add");
   // $process = proc_open('/var/www/html/websockets/add', $descriptorspec, $pipes);//creating child process
    $process = proc_open($child_proc, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);//creating child process
    sleep(1);

    if (is_resource($process))
    {

            //Read input.txt by line and store it in an array
            $input = file('/var/www/html/test/websockets/input.txt');

            //Feed the input (hardcoded)
            fwrite($pipes[0], "$input[0] $input[1]");

            fclose($pipes[0]);

            while ($s = fgets($pipes[1]))
            {
                print $s."</br>";
                flush();
            }

    ?>
```

Any guess why the code in the edit part is working where as when integrated in the client server application its output is not as expected.

Comment: I don't know if it occurred to you that `scanf("%d", &first);` leaves the new line on the `stdin` stream in your C program... Consider cleaning the buffer before calling `scanf` a second time...

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem I added fflush(stdin) between two scanf 's of C program but it does not work. It seems that the C program is not getting the input from stdin, I even tried to enter add newline i.e fwrite($stdin[0], "$input[0]\n$input[1]\n") but it also does not work.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour. Some implementations can deal with this, but it's generally not a good idea to rely on implementation specific trickery for something as trivial as this... it's as simple as this: `int c;` in a `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');`

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem no success. I have pasted a code under the edit label of my question and it works, please see the edit in the question.

Comment: What about actually checking what `$child_proc` looks like after you call `escapeshellcmd`. Not sure, but wouldn't that escape `./add` to `\./add`?

Comment: removing escapeshellcmd has no positive affect.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $child_proc = escapeshellcmd("unbuffer /var/www/html/test/websockets/./add")
```

the keyword unbuffer was causing the problem although it was there for some other reason but it was the one creating problem.